# Corrupted MySQL DB - Data not stored or erased on inserts on one table but when changing that table name the code works

Tags: php, mysql, corruption

I have a corrupted DB and i'm not sure what to do with it.  What happen is i have Flex app with a PHP backend where in some parts i need to do multiple inserts in a table, everything seems to work fine, no errors.    After running my code i make a select on that table and there's nothing showing up in the table.

I checked everything, i mean everything:

I checked login info. 
I trace the code up to the end, the query even shows up in workbench. 
I tried inserting with a direct string i made up myself and tested before in workbench, nada .

If i insert data directly from workbench it works.

After data has been inserted from workbench, i run it thru php and instead of updating the db it erase what i have previously inserted in workbench.

So i'm thinking something could be wrong with my computer setup ..., so i set up an environment on another machine.  No success here either same thing happens.

I then proceed to boot up an AWS machine with a different environment, same thing here too.

I tried to drop the table and recreate it manually, no success either.

**Last thing i did was create the table with a different name, bang that works from everywhere.**

Does anybody have clue what could happen here and some way to solve this has i don't want to change the table name, and by the way that table is not a new table and it was working fine before.

Comment: well what is this table name, also post any PHP with sql queries

Comment: Code works fine, i just create a new table from workbench just by changing the table name and then everything works.

Answer (score 0):

If you could give the table name that would be great. Perhaps it's a conflicting keyword you used in the table name that's causing your troubles?